# haskell pass map in parameter

Tags: haskell

how can I pass a Data.Map mapping Int to [Char] in haskell? How do the function header looks like? Let's assume that the function will return an int

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
someFunction :: <insert your answer here> -> Int
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A working and compilable example:

```
module Foo where
import qualified Data.Map as M
mapSize :: M.Map Int [Char] -> Int
mapSize m = M.size m
```

which lets you do things, say in GHCi, like

```
*Foo> let m = M.fromList [(2,"abc"), (3,"cde")] :: M.Map Int [Char]
*Foo> mapSize m
2
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you import `Data.Map`. If you import Data.Map unqualified (you most likely don't, this is why I choose it as example ;) ), it would be `Map Int [Char]`. How do I know? Simple, [documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html) says:

> `data Map k a`
>
> A Map from keys k to values a.

Comment: cool, and could you please provide some example with qualified import?

Comment: @coubeatczech: Oh come on, is it *that* hard? Common sense should be able to tell you the answer from here...

Answer (score 1):

Well, `const 5 :: Map Int [Char] -> Int`, for example.